# How to remove a starting url via powershell from an existing content source?

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to find a cmdlet to do this but I havent been able to.
I want to create a content source with a starting url, the problem is that url already exists on the default content source so I want to remove it from there. But I want to do it with powershell, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
$searchServiceName = "Your Search Service Application"
$addressToMove = "http://your/start/address"
$defaultContentSourceName = "Local SharePoint sites"

$searchService = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Identity $searchServiceName

$defaultContentSource = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -Identity $defaultContentSourceName -SearchApplication $searchService

if ($defaultContentSource.StartAddresses.Exists($addressToMove))
{
    $defaultContentSource.StartAddresses.Remove($addressToMove)
    $defaultContentSource.Update()
}



# then you can add $addressToMove to another content source
```

And I know this works, it is used as part of a deployment package for an application I'm working on, and has been tested and successfully deployed across several environments.

[Note: we use SharePoint Server 2010 / SharePoint Server Search, not Foundation or FAST, so I'm not sure how it would work in those cases, if that is your environment.]

Comment: I'd move the $defaultContentSource.Update() inside the IF.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the next powershell snippet:

```
$sourceName = "File"

$contentSSA = "FASTContent"

$source = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlContentSource -Identity $sourceName -SearchApplication $contentSSA

$startaddresses = $source.StartAddresses | ForEach-Object { $_.OriginalString }

$source.StartAddresses.Clear()

ForEach ($address in $startaddresses ){ $source.StartAddresses.Add($address) }
```

Reference: http://techmikael.blogspot.co.il/2011/06/clearing-items-from-specific-content.html

I tried it and it works.